# split video without knowing file duration

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I want to make chunks of a video each chunks not more than 3 minutes using ffmpeg.I have read about this command of ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -ss 0 -t 180 -c copy outputVideoSegment.mp4
```

I am using it in my code like

```
 String command = "ffmpeg -i videos/testing.vob  -ss 0 -t 180 -c copy outputVideoSegment.mp4";

            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", command);
            try {
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
                process.waitFor(); // to wait for process builder to finish the
                                    // process
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                log.error("Exception occured in making chunks due to " + exception.getCause());
            }
```

The above command working fine and spliting the video into 3 min, but in my case i have to read a file so i dont know exactly the duration of  file.Do i need to run above command inside the loop or any other way.Please help.

Comment: Thanks #aergistal , can you please share the proper ffmpeg command for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segment duration will be exactly 180s only if you have a keyframe present each 180s.

You can use `-c copy` only if your input video already has keyframes at the splitting points.

If it doesn't you must re-encode and add them before splitting:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 -f segment -segment_time 180 segment_%02d.mp4
```

where:

- `-g 250` [frames] adds a keyframe every 250 frames (10s at 25 fps)
- `-sc_threshold = 0` avoids inserting keyframes on scene-change
- `-segment_time 180` [s] creates segments of specified duration and must be a multiple of the keyframe interval

Comment: Thanks #aergistal for above command,its working fine but on playing first split video is playing well,but second and others split videos are coming black for few duration then play.

Comment: I don't know how you're using the segments exactly but you can try to add `-segment_format_options movflags=+faststart`

Comment: I just want my all chunks parts starts from where its previous ends.I am using like u suggest  ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0 -f segment -segment_time 20 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart videos/chunks/segment_%02d.mp4

Comment: Probably need to add `-reset_timestamps 1`